# A function which belongs on a concrete Besov Space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems

Please, anyone of you know a simple example of a function which belongs to the Besov Space with $p=q=\infty$ and $s=0$ (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ where $I$ is a closed interval). I think that the function given by
$$
\frac{1}{\log{\frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}}}}
$$
(perhaps just looking for a good $\alpha$) belongs to such space but I really don't know how to do the check.

In the other hand, and in the same way as above, some of you knows a kind of Weierstrass function, Takagi function, Minkowski question mark function,... such that it belongs to the Besov Space with $p=q=\infty$ and $s=0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably your question should include also a requirement that the function does _not_ belong in certain other subspace of $B^{0,\infty}_\infty$, otherwise there are a lot of trivial examples. 

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about $B^{0,\infty}_\infty$.

Take a function $u$ in the Zygmund class $B^{1,\infty}_\infty$, which the vector space of $L^\infty$ functions such that
$$\exists C,\forall x,h,\quad
\vert(u(x+h)+u(x-h)-2u(x)\vert\le C\vert h\vert.
$$

Note that $B^{1,\infty}_\infty\supset L^\infty\cap \text{Lipschitz}$
(here Lipschitz means
$\exists C,\forall x,h,\quad
\vert(u(x+h)-u(x)\vert\le C\vert h\vert
$).

Now the derivative of $u$ belongs to $B^{0,\infty}_\infty$.

In particular, first derivatives 
of functions in  $L^\infty\cap \text{Lipschitz}$ belong to $B^{0,\infty}_\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

A Guassian $e^{-x^2}$ should work.  A Guassian and it's Fourier transform decay exponentially fast.  Thus, by the Fourier transform description of Besov Spaces (the only one I'm familiar with, though I understand there are other definitions), this function works, and I think is even in any Besov space

Comment: Might as well just use $x\mapsto 0$.... $B^{s,p}_q$ is a vector space after all. 

Comment: ha, good point!